# ASP.NET Addition of two byte arrays

Tags: asp.net, arrays

I am looking at an exercise two added up two byte arrays

```
public AddByteResult ValuesAreAdded(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
   var result = AddBytes(a, b);
   return new AddResult(a, b, result);
}
```

with sample data and results given as

```
Input : { 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1 }

Result: {2,2,2}

Input : { 1, 1, 255 }, {0, 0, 1 }

Result: {1,2,0}
```

So obviously I need to work on function for adding the bytes, but where I am stuck is that I dont understand the additions of the above input. Can someone explain how those above results are calculated and what .NET offers to calculate the sum of byte arrays ?

Comment: Your second result makes no sense.

Comment: Aye that's what I was thinking, I was wondering how they came to that result. All I know is the method needs add the byte arrays recursively, but even before I got to that I was wondering if anyone here knew how they got to those results.

Comment: I understand positions 1 and 2 (the 2 and the 0), but not position 0 (the 1). I expected {2, 2, 0}

Comment: Could even explain those positions 1,2 how they came to those results ?

Comment: Position 1: 1 + 1 = 2. Position 2: 255 + 1 = 256. Since the maximum value a byte can store is 255, it overflows the byte back to 0. But for Position 0, it somehow has 1 + 1 = 1

Comment: But position 1 in the second example is 1 + 0 no ?

Comment: Oops, yeah. Had those backwards with an input from the first example. I expect {1, 1, 0}, and I don't know where the 2 in {1,2,0} comes from.

Comment: Ok yeah we are on the same page, I am going to just guess the result has a typo in it then. Thanks very much for your input

Comment: Funny... I read the the second result as (working from the right).... 255+1=0 for the right byte, carry 1 to the left (as you would working in decimal), which gives 1 from the input + 1 from the carry to give 2 for the middle byte, then 1 + 0 to give 1 for the left byte...

Comment: @forsvarir is this the way bytes are normally added together i.e. working from the right and carry over the one ?

Comment: Yes.. and no? It depend why you're doing it... for example, if you're running windows, start up calculator and put it in programmers mode, hex.  Add 101FF (1,1,255 in hex) to 1 (0,0,1 in hex) and you get 10200 (1,2,0 in hex)

Comment: So... if you're treating your byte arrays as numbers in big endian format and you're adding them with the expectation that you'll end up with another number in big endian format then it makes sense.  If the byte represent a little endian number then this approach wouldn't work and if they don't collectively represent a number at all then it will depend on what the algorithm is expecting you to do, but I would expect it to account for the overflow/carry situation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Naive code sample to explain what I'm suggesting in my comments (I'm sure that there are better ways of encoding the logic but hopefully it gets the gist across)...

```
    static public byte[] AddBytes(byte[] a, byte[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Mismatched array lengths is not currently supported");
        }

        byte[] result = new byte[a.Length + 1];
        int carry = 0;

        for (int x = a.Length - 1; x >= 0; x--)
        {
            int tempresult = a[x] + b[x] + carry;
            result[x + 1] =(byte)(tempresult); 
            carry = tempresult / (byte.MaxValue + 1); 
        }

        if (carry > 0)
        {
            // Carried into extra byte, so return it
            result[0] = (byte)carry;
            return result;
        }
        // no carry into extra byte, so remove it
        return result.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] a = { 1, 1, 1 };
        byte[] b = { 1, 1, 1 };
        byte[] c = { 1, 1, 255 };
        byte[] d = { 0, 0, 1 };
        byte[] e = { 255, 255, 255 };
        byte[] f = { 255, 255, 255 };

        var x = AddBytes(a, b);
        x = AddBytes(c, d);
        x = AddBytes(e, f);
    }
```

As I've said, this is essentially assuming that the byte array represents numbers...

So, {1,1,1} is equivalent to 0x10101 or 65793
65793 + 65793 = 131586 or 0x20202 i.e. {2,2,2}

and, {1,1,255} + {0,0,1} is equivalent to 0x101FF + 0x1 or 66047 + 1 = 66048 or 0x10200 i.e. {1,2,0}

Answer (score 0):

What you want it a function that adds 2 byte arrays recursively. Have a look at the following example, it does what you want:

```
private byte[] AddRecursive(byte[] f, byte[] s)
{
    int sum;
    byte[] r;
    int arrayLength = f.Length;

    if (f.Length == 0 || s.Length == 0)
    {
        return new byte[] { };
    }

    byte[] fCopy = new byte[f.Length - 1];
    byte[] sCopy = new byte[s.Length - 1];

    Array.Copy(f, fCopy, arrayLength - 1);
    Array.Copy(s, sCopy, arrayLength - 1);

    sum = Convert.ToInt16(f[arrayLength - 1] + s[arrayLength - 1]);           

    if (sum > 255)
    {
        r = new byte[] { sum == 510 ? Convert.ToByte(255) : Convert.ToByte(sum % 255 - 1) };

        bool found = false;
        for (int i = arrayLength - 2; i >= 0 && !found; i--)
        {
            if (fCopy[i] < 255)
            {
                fCopy[i] += 1;
                found = true;
            } else if (sCopy[i] < 255)
            {
                sCopy[i] += 1;
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if (!found)
        {
            if (fCopy.Length == 0 || sCopy.Length == 0)
            {
                fCopy = new byte[] { 0 };
                sCopy = new byte[] { 1 };
            }
            else
            {
                fCopy.Concat(new byte[] { 0 });
                sCopy.Concat(new byte[] { 1 });
            }
        }
    } else
    {
        r = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(sum) };
    }                   

    return AddRecursive(fCopy, sCopy).Concat(r).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  public class AddingThisAddingThat 
    {

        private int carry = 0;        
        public byte[] AddRecursive(byte[] a, byte[] b)
        {
            //Start from bottom of the byte[] array
            a = a.Reverse().ToArray();
            b = b.Reverse().ToArray();
            if (a.Length == 0) return new byte[] { };            
            int tempresult = a[0] + b[0] + carry;
            byte[] z = new byte[]
            { (byte)(tempresult) };
            carry = tempresult / (byte.MaxValue + 1);
            return z.Concat(AddRecursive(a.Skip(1).ToArray(), b.Skip(1).ToArray())).ToArray();
        }


    }

 public void TestSetup()
        {
            addthisaddthat = new AddingThisAddingThat();
        }

        [Test]
        public void Add_UsingARecursiveAlgorithm_ValuesAreAdded()
        {
            //First Test
            byte[] expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new byte[] { 1, 1, 1 }).Reverse().ToArray();
            Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 2, 2, 2 }));
            //Sec Test
            expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 1, 1, 255 }, new byte[] { 0, 0, 1 }).Reverse().ToArray();
            Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 1, 2, 0 }));
            //Third Test
            expectedResult = addthisaddthat.AddRecursive(new byte[] { 255, 255, 255 }, new byte[] { 255, 255, 255 }).Reverse().ToArray();
            Assert.That(expectedResult, Is.EqualTo(new byte[] { 255, 255, 254 }));
        }

        [OneTimeTearDown]
        public void TestTearDown()
        {
            addthisaddthat = null;
        }
```